# Erro ao instalar o spaCy

Tags: python, pip

Quando tento instalar o spaCy, eu recebo este erro:

```js
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\joaov_pu5ho3m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\joaov_pu5ho3m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h4h9784x\normal' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel 'murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0' 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2' 'thinc<7.4.0,>=7.3.0' 'preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (129 lines):
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/e9/411be1845f1ac07ae3bc40a4b19ba401819baed4fa63b4f5ef28b2300eb4/murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz
  Collecting cython>=0.25
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/44/6e5aee9916a53f56d32da0770962c9571f8267cd2327b9e58db656d61efe/Cython-0.29.14-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (1.6MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/8d/d095bbb109a004351c85c83bc853782fc27692693b305dd7b170c36a1262/cymem-2.0.3.tar.gz
  Collecting thinc<7.4.0,>=7.3.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/38/f79bb496ced36f8d69cdbdfe57a322205582ed9508bda5bd0227969d5a77/thinc-7.3.1.tar.gz
  Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/14/de231123ddbe0bf12bd9b1993122d67f22859643bee4dad3b6ce91986336/preshed-3.0.2.tar.gz
  Collecting blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/5a/f9b8a78e3d1fdde1b0215413d88ab55d907ab81f95b62418a6e9cda30dec/blis-0.4.1.tar.gz
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/ef/e8266e158ed32bf5f723fac862b6518833d0b53ca183165a8718f212c0d5/wasabi-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/5b/f83e478fbf44c0d04f182e56db0871a53f5096febb8eb0be7cec75dca73b/srsly-0.2.0.tar.gz
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/dd/45a5965b3406b39d0537a1de89727879f356db984fe82e918bfb9327aa04/numpy-1.17.4-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (10.7MB)
  Collecting plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/85/40b8f66c2dd8f4fd9f09d59b22720cffecf1331e788b8a0cab5bafb353d1/plac-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/32/5144caf0478b1f26bd9d97f510a47336cf4ac0f96c6bc3b5af20d4173920/tqdm-4.40.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Building wheels for collected packages: murmurhash, cymem, thinc, preshed, blis, srsly
    Building wheel for murmurhash (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for murmurhash (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for murmurhash: filename=murmurhash-1.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl size=18651 sha256=bbf36261fc2a613a7dd6785972db08398a1cf55ea9694710b7d366f84e747fb0
    Stored in directory: C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\77\f4\97\79cf3c5af8be5044c749bb449340a0f667ebb1d8c1f388cd65
    Building wheel for cymem (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for cymem (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for cymem: filename=cymem-2.0.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl size=28612 sha256=906099c6796f81617aeec3b751ef9e54d338d85f1fbd152d4b35792da5718bf9
    Stored in directory: C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\ec\63\9a\dd916ca28285b94bd1f1afcbcd2bb65c2cae7ed2b84f565d43
    Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): still running...
    Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for thinc: filename=thinc-7.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl size=1866919 sha256=9f9b1c70d30eddf95d4869c48eed6f3241334113bde130d4cd1483f0c75d637f
    Stored in directory: C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\81\ad\51\a0bca08bd4d13f009a0546e9955e6b8391e42136086c13dbf4
    Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for preshed: filename=preshed-3.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl size=93121 sha256=bab93f407971274ac7ab89786261b08165c8b2da43809b251572ab2889fe4dc6
    Stored in directory: C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\17\94\15\50a48f534bac3ff98ef0394ae81d03babf76545cf6270433ec
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\joaov_pu5ho3m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\drika\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k085n4r2\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\drika\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k085n4r2\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-xizz0669' --python-tag cp36
         cwd: C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k085n4r2\blis\
    Complete output (31 lines):
    BLIS_COMPILER? None
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    running build_ext
    C:\Users\joaov_pu5ho3m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k085n4r2\blis\blis\cy.pxd
      tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
    C:\Users\joaov_pu5ho3m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\drika\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k085n4r2\blis\blis\py.pyx
      tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
    Processing blis\cy.pyx
    Processing blis\py.pyx
    msvc
    py_compiler msvc
```

Eu já instalei o Visual Studio Build Tools C++, já executei como administrador
Especificações do sistema:
Windows 10
Python 3.6.2 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, eu fiquei muito tempo pra tentar resolver isso e é muito simples, desinstala o python 32 bits e instala o 64 bits
ai é só dar o pip install spacy e já era
espero que isso te ajude!

Comment: Infelizmente descobri que o meu SO é classificado como 32 bits, descobri isso após algumas buscas, mas vou marcar a resposta como correta para pessoas que tenham computadores com SO 64 bits possam resolver. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Como Tkr Dragon falou, o SpaCy precisa do python 64 bits, que obviamente, só funciona em SOs 64 bits.

Para quem tem um SO 32 bits e quer o POS Tagger em português (que nem o do SpaCy), pesquise "Portuguese-POS-tagger" e encontre o link do repositorio GITHUB de um projeto de POS Tagger.

Use "git clone" e mova o arquivo pickle para a pasta do seu projeto.

O conteudo do arquivo ".py" deve ser copiado para o seu arquivo Python.

Caso queira um tokenizador, o NLTK é uma boa solução.

O spacy é melhor e mais rapido em questão de tagger, mas para quem não tem um sistema 64 bits é uma solução muito boa o que recomendei!